# Hitting Return at start of line deletes leading whitespace. How to I prevent this?

Tags: whitespace

If I have a line of text in a file with leading whitespace, and I move to the beginning of that line and hit enter, the whitespace is deleted such that the first non-whitespace character is the first character of the line.

For example:

```
                Here is a line with leading whitespace.
```

becomes:

```
Here is a line with leading whitespace.
```

if I hit enter at the start of the line (or actually anywhere within the whitespace).

Is there any way to stop Emacs from doing this?  I would like to maintain the leading whitespace and just insert a new line.

Comment: Emacs only does this in modes where it is expected to make sense.  E.g. vanilla `emacs -Q foo.txt` does not do this because `foo.txt. will be in `text-mode`.  So you'll want to give more details about your example which can explain why you're seeing this.

Comment: I moved aside my `~/.emacs` file to remove any customizations, and started emacs via `emacs -Q foo.txt` as you describe.  I see that the file is in "Text" mode, but the leading whitespace is removed when I hit enter as I describe above.  I'm running GNU Emacs 26.3 in FreeBSD 12.1.  Not sure what other details you need - happy to provide them if there is anything in particular that would be helpful.

Comment: [ The `-Q` makes Emacs ignore the `.emacs` anyway.  ]  Curious, because I tested this on Emacs-26.3 just before sending my comment.  I did `emacs -Q foo.txt` where the file starts empty, then I did `SPC a RET` and the space before `a` remained and the cursor ended immediately under the `a`.  You get a different result?

Comment: I did get a different result.  You and I must have had different settings for electric-indent-mode (see below).  Not sure why, but now that I know about this mode I can customize as I need.  Thanks!

Comment: The `-Q` forces the default setting (which enables `electric-indent-mode` by default for me as well).  It's used specifically to factor out possible differences due to local configs.

Answer (score 2):

`C-h k RET` (or `M-x describe-key RET`) displays:

> RET (translated from ) runs the command newline [...]

> Insert a newline, and move to left margin of the new line if it’s blank. [...]

> If ‘electric-indent-mode’ is enabled, this indents the final new line
> that it adds, and reindents the preceding line.  To just insert
> a newline, use M-x electric-indent-just-newline.

I guess you have `electric-indent-mode` activated.

So you can either use `M-x electric-indent-just-newline` (and possibly bind this to the RET key) or disable `electric-indent-mode`.  You can add `(electric-indent-mode -1)` in your init file to disable it globally, or type `M-x electric-indent-local-mode` to disable it in the current buffer.

See the documentation for details (`C-h f electric-indent-mode`).

Comment: electric-indent-mode was exactly it... thanks so much!  I didn't find it in my searches because I was looking for features related to "leading whitespace".  It never occurred to me to search on "indent".  Thanks again!